# Paralleling MOSFET Oscillation

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, oscillation

I'm currently reading an application note about paralleling MOSFET and oscillation and it is written the following sentence :

"In addition, parallel MOSFETs share a common low-impedance path, which is also susceptible to parasitic oscillation."

What does it mean by low impedance path ? And why there is a low impedance path ? And why a low impedance path is susceptible to cause oscillations ?

Here is the application note (the sentence is written page 4):
https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=59458&prodName=TK8P65W

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 connection paths between 2 parallel FETs. You might think of them as 0 Ohms but every conductor has resistance and inductance and if near another insulated conductor automatically has some capacitance.  The semiconductor dielectric also has capacitance and it gets bigger with smaller RdsOn.  So in choosing a part with smallest gate capacitance, one will see that some parts have a lower and higher RC product from the normal distribution depending on the internal design of the FET.

The impedances are thus treated as 3 miniature transmission lines with inductance of ~ 0.5nH/mm and the output and junction capacitances lumped together in datasheets ; Coss,Ciss that are derived from Cds, Cgd, Cgs.

If you re-read the article, it tells you how that gets transformed into a Colpitt's Oscillator.  It also gets worse when Vt thresholds are mismatched. The oscillations  can be prevented by choosing a suitable low gate resistor for each gate.   The article shows where these ringing problems can occur during switching.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjVwbm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually don't understand why a low impedance path cause oscillations ?

Comment: Do you understand anything about the "RLC series resonance" characteristics. I inserted a 20MHz filter .  This is like a long leaded 10nF ceramic capacitor with a SRF of 20MHz. You can search for these keywords.

Comment: I think I understand. What is the link between low impedance and the attenuation in function of the frequency ? Do you mean that the resonnant frequency is linked to low impedance path ?

Comment: Yes. In series resonance LC becomes 0 and the R gets 100% of the input or 0dB loss.  in a positive feedback loop it will oscillate when the gain is > 1.  The lower the R, the higher the Q shape factor

Comment: Thank you very much :D